# Sort a data frame in python with duplicates by a string list

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have a data frame with a 250 names with values imported in python via pandas read_csv.
It reads in the data:

| name | val1 | val2 | val3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| George | 2.5 | 1.1 | 1.0 |
| George | 3.1 | 1.4 | 0.0 |
| George | 1.1 | 0.9 | 4.1 |
| Tom | 2.1 | 1.2 | -3.0 |
| Tom | 3.0 | -1.2 | 3.5 |
| Tom | 7.3 | 5.2 | -1.2 |
| Tom | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| Sally | 6.1 | 9.1 | -5.6 |
| Sally | 5.7 | 4.7 | 9.1 |

I want to reorder these by a particular order:

```
neworder = ['Sally', ..., 'George', 'Tom']
```

| name | val1 | val2 | val3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sally | 6.1 | 9.1 | -5.6 |
| Sally | 5.7 | 4.7 | 9.1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| George | 2.5 | 1.1 | 1.0 |
| George | 3.1 | 1.4 | 0.0 |
| George | 1.1 | 0.9 | 4.1 |
| Tom | 2.1 | 1.2 | -3.0 |
| Tom | 3.0 | -1.2 | 3.5 |
| Tom | 7.3 | 5.2 | -1.2 |
| Tom | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.1 |

In IDL I would do this with some `for` loops, but I suspect there's a sorting function in Python that my google skills have not been able to find.

Comment: Ya, I used the formatting that it requested, and it looked fine while editing. I tried reformatting it using a different method.

Comment: and the subsequent edit reveals why the table display was weird - the end of the table needs a blank line after it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a lookup dictionary for your sort somehow:

```py
name_order = {'Sally':1, ... , 'George':12, 'Tom':13} # hand-numbered
```

```py
neworder = ['Sally', ... , 'George', 'Tom']
name_order = {nm:ix for ix,nm in enumerate(neworder)} # generated
```

And then pass it in a lambda function to the key parameter:

```py
df.sort_values(by='name', key=lambda nm: nm.map(name_order))
```

I'd need to think a bit about what happened if an unexpected name appeared; you might be able to cope with this by making `name_order` a `collections.defaultdict`.

Comment: also look at pd.Categorical, if you assign the column with the list of categories as input, it will sort as per the categories when using `sort_values`

Comment: @Joffan The key function in sort values takes series as a argument and should return the series containing the sortorder, so here `nm` is the series so you cant pass series to access elements in dict. One way to solve this problem is to `map` the values using the `name_order` dictionary for e.g. you could do `df.sort_values(by='name', key=lambda nm: nm.map(name_order))`

Comment: Using the df.sort_values method I get:
`TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`

Comment: @ShubhamSharma thanks, that was unclear to me but I see how that's working now

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution

```
neworder = ['Sally', ... , 'George', 'Tom']
name_order = {nm:ix for ix,nm in enumerate(neworder)} # generated
df.sort_values(by='name', key=lambda nm: nm.map(name_order))
```

Thanks @Joffan and @ShubhamSharma